# Passing keyboard input for a running process (powershell script)

Tags: powershell

I have 3 powershell scripts. First one run second(monitor for third) and third(do some actions).
When execution of third one is done (it's called in blocking way (we are waiting for exit)), i want to tell second(monitor that is called in non-blocking way) to end his action and return some values. How should I do it? I am checking in monitor script if user pressed `s` key and return some values if true. I need to "press" that key in first script.
My code is like this:

```
#some code

$psi = new-object "Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"
$psi.FileName = "artillery"
$arguments = "my fancy args" 
$psi.Arguments = $arguments

$proc = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)

$psi2 = new-object "Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"
$psi2.FileName = "artillery_metric_getter.ps1" 
$proc2 = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi2)
$proc2.Start();

if ( $waitForExit ) {
        $proc.WaitForExit();
        $stdout = $proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        $stderr = $proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
        Write-Host "stdout: $stdout"
        Write-Host "stderr: $stderr"
                }
#here i want to "press 's' key for $proc2 and catch values he return
```

The code of powershell script that is called in `$proc2` is like:

```
for(($i=1),($i>0),($i++)){

#there is some code

$key = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()
if ($key.Character -eq 's') {
    
  $meanMemRet = 123 #there is some calc 
  $meanProcRet = 456 #there is some calc
  
  return $meanProcRet,$meanMemRet
}
}
```

TLDR: So we need to "press" 's' button in first script to stop execution of monitor script. How to do it?

Comment: do you need an out of process task here? why not use a runspace or a job?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I can use runspace and job. That's a modification on my script and i wrote it in way I know (i done some Diagnostics.Process in other scripts)

Comment: So would you be ok with an answer using Runspace? Or do you want it to be a Process? Again, your task is much easier to accomplish with a Runspace and more efficient too as Runspace are in the same process, different thread. However, it should be understood that the script invoking the runspace (`$proc2`) must block waiting for the task to complete or `s` key is pressed.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - of course that Runspace will be good. Honestly - i don't like using Diagnostics.Process here because it's a bit not understandable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're okay with having a solution using a [Runspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0), this is how you can approach your code. Worth noting, passing arguments to the runspace is fairly easy, certainly easier than passing arguments to a `Process`.

Example using [`.AddParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addparameters?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0):

```bash
[powershell]::Create().
    AddScript({
        param($Param1, $Param2)

        "$Param1 $Param2"
    }).
    AddParameters(@{ Param1 = 'Hello'; Param2 = 'World' }).
    Invoke()
```

In your case, you can add a `param` block to your `artillery_metric_getter.ps1`. It's also worth noting that, the script invoking `artillery_metric_getter.ps1` **must block**, awaiting for either an `s` key press or the task completion.

```bash
$ps = [powershell]::Create().
    AddScript('absolute\path\to\artillery_metric_getter.ps1', $false)

# hook the runspace with your PSHost, this is so all streams
# except Success and Error are redirected to your console
$rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($Host)
$rs.Open()
$ps.Runspace = $rs
$out = [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[psobject]]::new()
$task = $ps.BeginInvoke(
    [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[psobject]] $null, $out)

# wait here for the task to be completed
while (-not $task.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(200)) {
    # or, if `s` key is pressed
    if ([Console]::KeyAvailable -and [Console]::ReadKey($true).KeyChar -eq 's') {
        # stop the task
        $ps.Stop()
    }

    # you can add this here to know its actually looping
    'awaiting key press...'
    # and do other stuff here, otherwsie just leave this empty
}

if ($ps.HadErrors) {
    $ps.Streams.Error # You can find errors here
}

# and here is the output generated by your task
$out.ReadAll()

# dispose resources
if ($ps) {
    $ps.Dispose()
}

if ($rs) {
    $rs.Dispose()
}
```

---

Following up from comments, since the runspace is hooked to your `$Host` listening on `s` key press is also possible inside it, using this as an example for `artillery_metric_getter.ps1`:

```bash
while ($true) {
    if ([Console]::KeyAvailable -and $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey().Character -eq 's') {
        return 'hello world'
    }

    [datetime]::Now.ToString('u')
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
}
```

Then from your main thread you leave the while loop empty, blocking until the task is done (until `s` key is pressed):

```bash
$ps = [powershell]::Create().
    AddScript('absolute\path\to\artillery_metric_getter.ps1', $false)

$rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($Host)
$rs.Open()
$ps.Runspace = $rs
$out = [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[psobject]]::new()
$task = $ps.BeginInvoke(
    [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[psobject]] $null, $out)

while (-not $task.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(200)) { }

$out.ReadAll()
```

Comment: Can I start both scripts (artillery and artillery_metric_getter.ps1) inside one Runspace?
I want to "press" s char inside this parent script, not press it directly on keyboard in console. In  other words - i need to pass to that artillery_metric_getter.ps1 script signal that 's' is pressed.
while (-not $task.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(200)) - $task will never be completed except we "press" s.

Comment: @TheTrainer sure you can but I assume `artillery` is an executable? or why is it not part of `artillery_metric_getter.ps1`?

Comment: yes, artillery is executable

Comment: @TheTrainer so `artillery_metric_getter.ps1` is the one that needs to stops `artillery` basically?

Comment: No, artillery runs some tests and artillery_metric_getter.ps1 getting metrics from otlp collector. When tests (artillery) are finished artillery_metric_getter.ps1 should be stopped and collected data from it.
So artillery needs to stop artillery_metric_getter.ps1

Comment: @TheTrainer does that update make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256957/discussion-between-the-trainer-and-santiago-squarzon).

Answer (score 0):

Let me offer an alternative approach, using the [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) cmdlet, which is in essence a friendly wrapper around the runspace APIs that can be used with the same job-management cmdlets as the child process-based background jobs (created with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)).

- `Start-ThreadJob` comes with [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) and in Windows PowerShell can be installed on demand with, e.g., `Install-Module ThreadJob -Scope CurrentUser`.

The following, self-contained sample code:

- Assumes that you have control over the monitoring code to be run in the background and that you simply need *some* signaling mechanism for the main thread to instruct the monitoring code to exit and return a result, which is achieved by way of a [custom event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-event).
- It shows only the interaction between the main thread and the background monitoring code, created with `Start-ThreadJob` (the equivalent of your `artillery_metric_getter.ps1` script).

  - It sounds like in your scenario you can simply run your `artillery` command by *direct, synchronous invocation*, which allows you to capture the output streams directly, if needed:

    ```bash
    # Invoke artillery directly, synchronously; output to the console.
    # Process exit code will be reflected in $LASTEXTICODE
    artillery my fancy args

    # Alternatively, capture both stdout and stderr output.
    $stdoutLines, $stderrLines = 
       (artillery my fancy args 2>&1).Where({ $_ -is [string] }, 'Split')
    ```
- The simulated monitoring code checks for the custom exit event raised by the main thread in a *polling loop*, via [`Get-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-event), and produces output indefinitely until the custom event is received.

  - To *synchronously* wait for the event - akin to waiting for a keystroke - use [`Wait-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-event), though note that this may not be necessary, given that jobs produce their output in the background anyway, and require the caller to collect the output on demand via [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job).
    That is, in general you could just let the thread job run its course and let it exit automatically, then collect the results when needed.
- See the source-code comments for further information.

```bash
# Choose the name of a custom event.
# Note that NO event registration is strictly necessary: 
#  * Events with that name can be generated without further preparation, with
#    New-Event or - in the case at hand, due to cross-runspace use - via 
#   .Events.GenerateEvent() on the target runspace.
#  * The target runspace can use Wait-Event or Get-Event to check for such
#    events, or use Register-EngineEvent -Action { ... } to process events
#    asynchronously, via a dynamic module in which the script block runs.
$eventName = 'StopProcessing'

# Start a thread job that performs operations in the background.
$jb = 
  Start-ThreadJob {
    # ... Do things indefinitely, until the event of interest arrives
    #     and signals the desire to exit.
    # NOTE: Get-Event -SourceIdentifier $using:eventName *should* work, but
    #       as of v7.4.1 *doesn't*: see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11705
    while (-not (Get-Event).Where({ $_.SourceIdentifier -eq $using:eventName }, 'First')) {
      # ... do work here.
      '.' # Sample output.
      Start-Sleep 1
    }
    # Write an information message and exit.
    Write-Information 'Exit requested.'
  }
# Get the thread job's runspace, assumed to be the most recently created.
# Note:
#  Ideally, the runspace reference would be determined via the thread-info 
#  object, but I'm not aware of a way to do that.
$rs = Get-Runspace | Select-Object -Last 1

Write-Verbose -Verbose @"
A sample thread job is now running indefinitely, producing output in the
background that must be collected explicitly later, with Receive-Object.
The sample job outputs a "." for every second of its runtime.

Press ENTER to signal it to stop via a custom event,
and then collect its output:
"@
Read-Host

# Generate custom event in the thread job's runspace.
# Note: For the .Events property on the runspace to be populated, the job must
#       apparently be in the Running state, so we must wait for that.
#       (Due to the Read-Host above, this is unlikely to be necessary here,
#       but applies in general.)
while ($jb.State -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
# Note: This is the equivalent of calling New-Event -SourceIdentifier $eventName,
#       only triggered runspace-externally.
$null = $rs.Events.GenerateEvent(
  $eventName,  # sourceIdentifier (event name)
  $null,       # event sender - not needed here
  $null,       # event arguments - not needed here
  $null        # additional data - not needed here.
)

# The job is now assumed to have received the event and exited.
# Collect the results now and output them.
# Note: 6>&1 is used to surface Write-Information's output.
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Collecting and outputting job results..."
$jb | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob 6>&1
```